# Is it true that if E is a Lebesgue measurable set, such that it´s measure is finite, then E is bounded?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{L},\lambda)$ be a measure space, with $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure. Is the following statement true?
Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, be a $\lambda$-measurable set, such that $\lambda(E)<+\infty$, then $E$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - for example, consider $E := \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [n, n + 2^{-n}]$.  (Or for a more extreme example, consider that $\mathbb{Q}$ has measure 0.)

Answer (score 1):

No.
AT the point $(i, 0, 0, \cdots, 0)$, with $i \in \mathbb{N}$, center a ball of measure $2^{-i}$. The set of balls is unbounded but with measure $2$.